# Howto configure two mail servers (failover) in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, symfony-mailer

As stated in the [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#high-availability) it is possible, to add a failover configuration for mail servers:

> Symfony's mailer supports high availability via a technique called "failover" to ensure that emails are sent even if one mailer server fails.
>
> A failover transport is configured with two or more transports and the failover keyword:
>
> `MAILER_DSN="failover(postmark+api://ID@default sendgrid+smtp://KEY@default)"`
>
> The failover-transport starts using the first transport and if it fails, it will retry the same delivery with the next transports until one of them succeeds (or until all of them fail).

Is it possible to use and configure this feature in TYPO3? If so, how?

Can other configurations like `TLS Peer Verification` ([Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#tls-peer-verification)) of the Symfony mailer be configured in TYPO3?

> By default, SMTP transports perform TLS peer verification. This behavior is configurable with the verify_peer option. Although it's not recommended to disable this verification for security reasons, it can be useful while developing the application or when using a self-signed certificate:
>
> `$dsn = 'smtp://user:pass@smtp.example.com?verify_peer=0';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both features are currently not available as configuration in TYPO3. Can you please create 2 issues at https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues?

Of course via e.g. XCLASS or maybe there is an event it is possible to add such stuff via extension.

Comment: Thanks! The issues are created: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/96033 and https://forge.typo3.org/issues/96034.